# Run partial parts of the an angular application from another app

Tags: node.js, angular

Is possible to run partial parts of an angular4 app to get the result of the workflows triggered like the test cases do from another app?

Comment: If your modules and components are reusable and compact. Yes you can use them

Comment: @Simonare 
we want to run the partial code of one service(angular4) from an nodejs app, more or less is like running a test case, but not from jest from an nodejs app